# $(6x+2)(x+5)(x+15)(x+18)+360=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$(6x+2)(x+5)(x+15)(x+18)+360=0$$
I was able to write the equation in the following form $$(3x+1)(x+5)(x+15)(x+18)+180=0$$ I don't know what to do from here on.

Let us look at the equation $$(x+2)(x+5)(x+15)(x+18)+360=0$$ instead.

Comment: Is the question definitely stated correctly? If so, it looks like you'll need the solution to the general quartic.

Comment: Where does this equation come from ? It has no "simple" solution.

Comment: The given answers are $-10\pm2\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: @mat1 Those are not roots of the polynomial you posted. Check for typos.

Comment: @dxiv, I did. $\text{}$

Comment: @mat1 $\;6x+2 \,\mapsto\, x+2\,$ will give you those roots (and two more easy ones).

Comment: @dxiv, well, there's the probability that there is a mistake in the book.

Comment: That's why the source of the problem is important to know. What book?

Comment: @mat1 Hint for the edited equation: $\;2+18=5+15\,$ so the factors are pairwise symmetric about $\,10\,$.

Comment: @dxiv, excuse me, how does this help?

Comment: @mat1 you can try grouping them as $[(x+2)(x+18)][(x+5)(x+15)]+360=0$ and assume $x^2+20x=k$.